# when I use the 'Go live' extension I got 'failed to load resources erorr'

Tags: javascript, web-development-server, liveserver

I tried this simple code to show that I can't reach the constant list I defined in the editor

[image: 1]

```js
for (let i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
  console.log('ali')
}
const ali = [1, 2, 3, 4];
```

Comment: That error doesn't matter. You can ignore it.

Comment: maybe you meant `console.log( ali )`?